# uidatadetectortypes of uiwebview to use more than one

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I am using the code below to set the uidatadetectortypes of my uiwebview.

```
webview.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Is there a way to add more than one datadetectortypes? Let's say i want the uiwebview to detect UIDataDetectorTypeLink and UIDataDetectorTypePhones .

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UIDataDetectorTypeLink | UIDataDetectorTypePhones`